# ValidationTechnicalProfile is not executed - B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to call a RESTful technical profile by using ValidationTechnicalProfile. I have checked application insights and I can see the OutputClaimsTransformations happening, but it skips over the ValidationTechnicalProfile and continues on with the next step. I have tried adding the RESTful technical profile as an Orchestration Step, and that works without any issues.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

SignInWithIdProvider.xml

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="__TenantId__" PolicyId="B2C_1A_SignInWithIdProvider" PublicPolicyUri="http://__TenantId__/B2C_1A_signin_idprovider">
<BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>__TenantId__</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
</BasePolicy>
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignInWithIdProvider"/>
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <SingleSignOn Scope="Policy"/>
        <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
        <SessionExpiryInSeconds>1800</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
        <JourneyFraming Enabled="true" Sources="__JourneyFramingSource__"/>
        <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
        <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sessionId" PartnerClaimType="sid"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="securityLevel" PartnerClaimType="acr"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="personalIdentificationNumber" PartnerClaimType="pid"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
        </OutputClaims>
        <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Snippet from TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

```
<ClaimsProvider>
<Domain>Signin</Domain>
<DisplayName>Signin using provider</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="OIDC-SignIn">
        <DisplayName>Sign-in</DisplayName>
        <Description>Login with provider</Description>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
        <Metadata>
            <Item Key="METADATA">__WellKnown__</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">__SignInClientId__</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">id profile</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="SingleLogoutEnabled">false</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="__SignInSecret__"/>
        </CryptographicKeys>
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ui_locales" DefaultValue="{Culture:RFC5646}"/>
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sessionId" PartnerClaimType="sid"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="securityLevel" PartnerClaimType="acr"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="personalIdentificationNumber" PartnerClaimType="pid"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss"/>
        </OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-PostNewSession" ContinueOnError="true"/>
        </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
```

```
<ClaimsProvider>
<DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-PostNewSession">
        <DisplayName>Post new session</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://some.apim.url/post-method</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_UserName"/>
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_Password"/>
        </CryptographicKeys>
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sessionId"/>
        </InputClaims>
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
```

```
<UserJourney Id="SignInWithIdProvider">
<OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>objectId</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
        </Preconditions>
        <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="idSignInExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="OIDC-SignIn"/>
        </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
        </Preconditions>
        <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AlternativeSecurityId-NoError"/>
        </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
</UserJourney>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation technical profiles only work from selfAsserted technical profiles.

> Only self-asserted technical profiles can use validation technical profiles. If you need to validate the output claims from non-self-asserted technical profiles, consider using an additional orchestration step in your user journey to accommodate the technical profile in charge of the validation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile

Adding it as an orchestration step would work.

Comment: Thank you, that explains why it didn't work :) 

Do you know if it's possible to add an "empty" selfAsserted technical profile that only exists to validate the RESTful technical profile? 
Adding the RESTful technical profile directly to the user journey works, but we want to use the ContinueOnError="true" feature.

Comment: You can, but to display a selfAsserted TP, it must have at least one field (output claim) to obtain from user entry. Which means a page will get displayed, and then youll need to use JS to submit it after page load, which will then execute your VTP. The UX maybe compromised.